# Can i use geth for other purposes than mining

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, exchanges

As you can understand from question, Iam totally new to crypto currencies. I have a node running on amazon linux ec2 instance.

I do NOT want to use it for mining. I want to create and manage accounts and do transactions with them.

- I want to interact from browser rather than command line. Is that possible with [geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) Or did I pick the wrong application? If not geth please suggest another OR combination of others.
- Also how much will it take to start geth completely so that I can run commands. I start node by following command

> go-ethereum/build/bin/geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*"

- I usually end up doing Ctrl+C Is that okay?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can i use geth not for mining?

In order to run geth in mining mode you must use [`--mine` option](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options), that's option **is disabled by default**.

> I want to interact from browser rather than command line. Is that
>   possible with geth?

In theory yes you can write you own client and interact with geth node by rpc api from the browser.

> How much will it take to start geth completely so that I can run
>   commands.

If you're talking about syncing database process it depends on many factors.

> I usually end up doing Ctrl+C Is that okay?

Since `Ctrl+C` send `INT` signal to the process it's OK to interupt program with that command.

Comment: I don't want to mine ether. Just run a node. Create accounts in it and do transactions if possible

Comment: Can account creation be done by rpc..? I enable it everytime I start geth

Comment: yes, account creation can be done by rpc, read the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki)

Comment: I saw this(https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts) before. But it only says about creating accounts and checking balanace. I want to be able to transfer coins to these accounts from exchanges. Is that possible ?

Comment: yes it's possible.

Comment: is it okay if i write curl function to do the account creation and manging stuff?

Comment: yes, that's normal, but using some libs must be better, shell functions is fragile I assume.

Answer (score 0):

A geth client only mines a cryptocurrency in a network if you type the command

> miner.start(eth.accounts[i])

Where eth.accounts[i] corresponds to the account address you want to use while mining. Unless you type the above command the geth client will not mine any ethereum or cryptocurrency.

> I want to interact from the browser rather than command line. Is that possible with geth Or did I pick the wrong application? If not geth please suggest another OR combination of others.

If you want a user interface to interact with the chain you can use the official client by ethereum foundation [available here](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases) which provides a good interface for the same.

> Also how much will it take to start geth completely so that I can run commands. I start node by the following command
>   $ go-ethereum/build/bin/geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*"

By using above command you are starting a full node in the network. The full node will first download the whole blockchain from the genesis block, recompute e each and every transaction in the blockchain, create the whole database(state-trie) for the same. This will take at least a couple of days or weeks to fully synchronize with the network. The synchronization process will start as soon as you connect with a peer in the network.

Additionally if you want faster starting time, you may consider using

> $go-ethereum/build/bin/geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*" --syncmode "fast"

or

> $go-ethereum/build/bin/geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*" --syncmode "light"

Please do read about what is light and fast syncmode corresponds to.

Comment: Is mist an RPC client like web3js ?

Comment: I want to run ethereum node and create accounts with public address. Will I be able to transfer coin to such a public address from bitrex ?